# Books similar to Thinking Mathematically(John Mason)

Tags: general-topology, problem-solving, education, book-recommendation, learning

Can anyone suggest me a book/notes/tips similar Thinking Mathematically?

I believe, apart from just plainly practicing a lot of problems(at University level math like topology, graph theory etc.,), there are other ways to get little better at solving problems by thinking about approaching a problem, complementing plain practice of solving.

Comment: Maybe [How to solve it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It) from Polya.

Comment: His longer 2-vol works on the same subject are better (Math Discovery, and Math and Plausible reasoning); should be in the univ lib. If you are interested in analysis, his 2 vol work with Szego is even better, but at a more advanced level.